# Install reliance Driver software in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, drivers, software-installation

I'm Using Huawei ec 150 dongle. I need to install [driver software](http://www.reliancenetconnect.co.in/others/Huawei%20New%20Dialer%20-%206085%20New%20Chipset.zip) It is quiet a big task for begineers in linux. So i took this matter over here.

**EDIT**

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 12d1:140b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. Media Keyboard K200 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: You can download the driver for your device from the link you have mentioned in your question. After downloading, extract download files and folder somewhere. Now open terminal and `cd` to  the Linux directory in your extracted folder. Now type `sudo bash install` to start your driver installation.

Comment: take a look [this post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=94078)

Comment: @Guru Could you explain with pictures.

Comment: @Guru It installed well . However the network is not detected.

Comment: /home/umar/Desktop/Huawei New Dialer - 6085 New Chipset/Huawei New Dialer - 6085 New Chipset/Linux

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if 14.04 would be different from 13.10 in this matter, but in my 13.10 installation, and with Huawei EC1260 (device shown in lsusb for my Reliance Netconnect dongle), I never had to install any driver or dialer.

Cold start your computer.
Insert the dongle.
Wait till a message pops up near the indicator panel about a new device.
[image]
Then click the network icon in the indicator panel and you will see new device entry - click that.
[image]
Follow the images below - select India in country, select Reliance in ISP.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Click on Apply will show popup message about registering the home network.
[image]

Now click on network icon again and open Edit Connections.
[image]
Select Reliance and click Edit.
[image]

In the Mobile Broadband tab enter your 10 digit mobile number both in the username and password.
[image]

Now click indicator panel network icon again and click on Reliance Connection... you should be connected...
[image]

Comment: It works. however there are some draw backs also. It is not applicable for unlimited plan. Even i disabled broadband it is not connected.

Comment: This is how i'm presently connected.. yet there are few problems. Once crossed broadband data limit. it does not allow further networking.

Comment: The network connection at the Operating System side has nothing to do with the data limit. You should actually subscribe to the unlimited plans.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded and extracted the software in desktop

Then performed the following actions in terminal with root previlage

> su
>
> > cd /home/umar/Desktop/Huawei New Dialer - 6085 New Chipset/Huawei New Dialer - 6085 New Chipset/Linux
> >
> > > sudo bash install

It is Installed but now the problem is it doesn't detect my device. [image]